# .htaccess rewrite rules do not work properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This .htaccess file rewrites to /admin/index.php when I open url like this:
http://example.com/admin/

But on http://example.com/admin/accounts/ rewrites request to /index.php (first rule).

What is wrong in my config file?

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Move your second and third rule to just under `RewriteEngine on`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last two rules are being ignored because the first rule supersedes them, by way of matching everything `(.*)`.

As such, the last two rules should be moved up to just under `RewriteEngine on`.